# The entirety of my writing is being crossed off. "Has vs Does, "came more" vs "comes"

Tags: grammar, auxiliary-verbs

I wrote, "Jane Doe has not let the expectations of work. . ."
Instead, I was told to write, "Jane Doe does not let the expectations of work. . ."

Was what I wrote in error? Every time I wrote "has" I am told to replace it with "does" without any context as to why.

Another example:
". . . with that came more responsibilities" I was told to replace "came more" with "comes". Where was the error in saying "came more"? The subject's past position had changed, which is why I spoke in the past tense.

Is my grammar that bad? Everything I wrote was crossed off without context as to why I should delete what I wrote.

Background: I am a British English learner who lives in the US if that helps. This level of correction is making me feel like I have a long way to go.

Comment: We would need more context to know. The phrases you cite are all acceptable: not right or wrong by themselves, but justified or unjustified depending on the context.

Comment: Who crossed it off? If you are using an online resource, some of them are terrible. In any case, we really need to see complete sentences (or even more) to know whether what you wrote is good or not **in context**.